# Chrome Extension listener to detect switching desktops on OS X

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm currently developing a chrome extension which needs to track the currently active tab, or the lack thereof. I have the following listeners running in the background:

`chrome.windows.onFocusedChanged`
`chrome.windows.onCreated`
`chrome.idle.onStateChanged`
`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`
`chrome.tabs.onActivated`

The issue is that when I have a chrome window full screened on my Mac, and three finger swipe away from it, `chrome.windows.onFocusedChanged` doesn't activate, which means that my extension believes that the last tab is still active even though the user has switched away from the chrome window. Is there a way to detect when a user switches away from a full screen chrome window on OS X?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a bug, report it on https://crbug.com (could be reported already, use search). The docs say that chrome.windows.onFocusChanged callback receives `chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_NONE if all chrome windows have lost focus`.

Comment: Assorted candidates: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=516740 https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=391471